# Numerically finding the eigenvalues of some Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, computational-physics, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

I have an expression for $H_{n,l,n',l'}$ (meaning $\left\langle n,l\left|H\right|n',l'\right\rangle $) for all allowed $n,l,n',l'$ values for some $n,n'<=N$. I guess that is a trivial question, but how can I find the eigenvalues in this case? There are 4 indices, so I can't construct a matrix and diagonalize it. Any suggestions?

*I'm looking only at $m=0$

Comment: You can always do the following (0,0)->0, (0,1)->1, (0,2)->2, ... (0,N)->N, (1,0)->N+1, ...(N,N)->N^2 etc. Then your basis is again associated with a single index and you can construct your matrix for diagonalization.

Answer (score 3):

The expression $|n^\prime, l^\prime\rangle$ is a vector and so is $H|n^\prime, l^\prime\rangle$. The fact that there are two (or more) labels to the vector does not stop it from being a vector; it does not become a matrix (or a tensor). You can always choose an appropriate basis for the space of $\{|n^\prime, l^\prime\rangle\}$ and carry out the diagonalization in the usual way.